# jQuery 307 authentication required in php

Tags: php, jquery

first screen shot from mozill in clients system.

[image]
![enter image description here][2![![]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/expTL.jpg)
  ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/expTL.jpg)

clicking of upc/gtin pop on clicking opens another pop up.That file name is formlist.php
  The above functionlity works everywhere and all browsers .**But problem exist in particular user 'marketing' network only in clients area not any where else**.
but since i am not able to replicate this error i could not understand why it is happening.
i am here write the code for jquery post for formlist.php which i have used in grid.php.

I have attached screen shot here with for refrence.if things are not clear.please let me know and please help me in finding solution.Thanks in advance

```
enter code here


function showdetailsnew(divid)
{

      var divid=divid;
      var popmodal="second";
      var form="formupc";

       $('.overlay-bg').show(); //display your popup
       $.post('formlist.php',


      { id: divid,popmodal:popmodal,form:form }, function(data) 
      {
           $('.overlay-content').html(data);
       }); 



}
```

Comment: could you please take out ur comment with site link. ihave corrected my mistake

Comment: I have deleted my comment and please set authentication for all pages ie. login required.